# Read new user agent string from Windows on IE with javascript

Tags: javascript, windows, internet-explorer

I'm installing app which add some new string into userAgent on Windows regedit.
Is it possible to read new modified userAgent from regedit with `navigator.userAgent` in IE without any reload or refresh?

Maybe there are some other workarounds...

Thanks for any help.

Comment: @ViniciusMonteiro I put some string into regedit to indicate our application is installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot read the registry with your browser or with javascript. This is by design due to the security concerns it raises. But whatever 'user agent' string you already updated in your registry, will be available to the javascript, as the browser sends that information to the server.

If you changed the registry while the browser is running, it may not be available, unless you re-start your browser.

Hope this helps.